# Problems while generating quickstart example with bjam

Tags: boost-python

I have being trying to use boost::python for first time and I begun with the included tutorials, but I feel dissapointed because I am not even able of building nothing after one whole working day.

My development tools are Python37, Boost1.69, VS 2017 and Windows 10 OS. Both the Python interpreter and the binaries for Boost are 64 bits version.

I built bjam.exe in "Z:/EXTERNOS/boost_1_69_0/tools/build", but I did not include in the system path (I tested including it and I got same errors). I am using the next "user-config.bjam" file in the folder indicated by ECHO %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%:

```
import toolset : using ;
using msvc : 14.1 ;
using python 
  : 3.7  # Version
  : "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe"  # Interpreter
  : "C:/Program Files/Python37/include"  # inc dir
  : "C:/Program Files/Python37/libs"  # link libs
  : # conditions
  ;
```

Then I changed to folder "Z:/EXTERNOS/boost_1_69_0/libs/python/example/quickstart" in the command console and run this sentence:

```
Z:\EXTERNOS\boost_1_69_0\tools\build\bjam.exe
```

The output in the console is next:

```
"C:/Program" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
...found 26 targets...
...updating 6 targets...
compile-c-c++ extending.obj
extending.cpp
extending.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'boost/python/class.hpp': No such file or directory

    call "..\bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.1\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul
 cl /Zm800 -nologo @"extending.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ extending.obj...
...skipped <p.>extending.pyd for lack of <p.>extending.obj...
...skipped <p.>extending.pdb for lack of <p.>extending.obj...
compile-c-c++ embedding.obj
embedding.cpp
embedding.cpp(6): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'boost/python.hpp': No such file or directory

    call "..\bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.1\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul
 cl /Zm800 -nologo @"embedding.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ embedding.obj...
...skipped <p.>embedding.exe for lack of <p.>embedding.obj...
...skipped <p.>embedding.pdb for lack of <p.>embedding.obj...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 4 targets...
```

I have noticed that a lot of people has had problem with issues close to this, but testing solutions provided to them seems not working for me.

Any idea about what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with bjam again for a while, I gave up and began to search another easier method. There are some of them: using CMake, python disutils... but the one I found the best for people used to work with c++ and msvc ide the next one:

- Use VS (tested with versions from 2010 to 2017, not sure about earlier ones).
- Create and empty console application and set it as a shared library.
- Setup everything in VS to find required boost and python folders, both includes and libraries.
- Program the c++ code of the boost::python tutorials and compile it (remember that x86 or 64 bits environmet must match with the python interpreter installed).
- Go to the results folder and change .dll extension for .pyd extension.
- Test it openning a console command in that same result folder and launching the Python interpreter, importing and calling any of the methods.

Far away easier that the official bjam system!